# Отправка Json на сервер через POST

Tags: json, angularjs, http, post

```
function($http) {
            this.sendJson = function () {
                var parameter = JSON.stringify({type:"user"});
                $http({
                    url: basePath + '/task/hello',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: parameter,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }, function errorCallback() {
                    alert("Ошибка");
                });
            };
        }
```

На сервере

```
public function actionHello()
    {
        var_dump($_POST);die;
}
```

В Network панели разработчика браузера, ответ от сервера

```
   array(0) {}
No Properties
```

пробовал разные варианты. Пустой пост. Что делаю не так?

Comment: стоит наверное дописать что за сервер используете

Comment: Пока тестирую на локалке (XAMPP), но отправляться запрос будет на nginx если вы об этом. Дописывать нужно в $http запросе?

Comment: не, я имел ввиду скорее про php, там может какую библиотеку и т.д.

Comment: хз в чем проблема. заменил headers на headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'} и все норм

Comment: скорее всего в настройках серверной стороны